# Location on circle where tangent intersects a point in space

Tags: trigonometry

Given a point in space (x, y), and a circle with a radius (r) centered at (a, b), how would I calculate the point on the diameter of the circle where the tangent would pass through point (x, y)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

draw a straight link down from the point (a,b) to the tangent point on the circle.

Do you see the right angle triangle formed? Can you then determine the length?

Comment: I know the shortest side is the length of the radius, and the longest side would be the difference in the positions of the circle center and the point.  I can then calculate the distance between the 2 points, so yes I can find the distances of all the points involved.

Comment: And that should give you the right answer, good luck